# Large ModelVisual3D stops being rendered

Tags: c#, helix-3d-toolkit, viewport3d

I'm trying rending a fairly sizable (triangle count and span over the `Viewport3D`) `ModelVisual3D` which disappears if the last triangle (in the `MeshGeometry3D` of the model) leaves the screen, despite other parts of the model still being on screen.  The particular problem triangle is circled in red in the image below.  I say it's a large model, but when it's rendering properly it doesn't drop frame the frame rate.  There are, however, about 150 of the green arches, all in the same mesh.  Interestingly, the blue line does not exhibit the same problem.

I can work around the problem by breaking up the model into smaller pieces.  But, that's not ideal.

Things that don't work:

- Setting `Viewport3D.ClipToBounds` to `false`.
- Modifying
  `FarPlaneDistance` or `NearPlaneDistance`

It may be worth noting that this is being hosted in `WinForms`.

[image]

EDIT: I take it back, the problem still exists even if I break up the model, just on a smaller scale (the last triangle of each model must remain on screen).

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it, but I don't understand the reason it works.

It looks like something about the point spacing around the corners being too small was causing a problem.  I reduced the spacing to .1 units and that seems to work.

If someone knows the reason this could be a problem, I'd love to hear it.